# renaming Server 2008 R2 NLB Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-nlb

I need to replace an existing web app server with an NLB cluster pair of servers which are already converged under a certain name/IP address. I will rename the standalone server first, then rename the existing NLB cluster to take over the name currently used by the standalone server. Would it be better or easier to just break the current NLB cluster, and reconverge it with the new name/IP? Are there any gotchas with renaming an NLB cluster to be aware of?

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you but one "gotcha" for this is AD replication time. Once you rename the old server you may need to wait a couple minutes before you can create the NLB cluster record that takes over the old name. Don't promise to get the swap-over done in less than 20-30 minutes!

Comment: Good thought. I'll definitely get at least an hour window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this will be as simple as changing the Full Internet name parameter of the NLB cluster (via the cluster manager) and then updating DNS with the new name/IP.

**Below is an excerpt From the Microsoft help file in the NLB Manager:**

*The Full Internet name parameter specifies a full Internet name for the NLB cluster (for example, cluster.microsoft.com). This name is used for the cluster as a whole, and it should be the same for all hosts in the cluster. If you alias several names for the cluster, enter the primary (main) name here. This name should be resolvable to the cluster's primary IP address through your DNS server or Hosts file.*

Comment: If nothing else, this makes it clear that you can have secondary (alias) names too. So you could just add the new name as a secondary and then make the DNS update to point the secondary name at the cluster name or IP.